# How to execute mysql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use my custom query to look for records in Rails (MySQL)? I have a little bit more complicated query, including join and I don't know how to use it? I stumpled upon `"find_by_sql"` method but it is pointless since its returning Array insted of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

EDIT my query looks similar to this:

```
"select students.id, students.school_id from students join schools on schools.id = students.school_id where schools.name LIKE '%#{search}%'"
```

Comment: Activerecord has support for joins, if you can you give an example of the query you are looking to run, then we can probably tell you how to use the active record query interface to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this should work, assuming you are using `Student` and `School` for your model names:

```
Student.joins(:school).where("schools.name LIKE '%#{search}%")
```